# Conservation of lepton number in neutrino oscillation

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, leptons

I was wondering how neutrino oscillations are possible and lepton number is conserved, as for example in the decay of an anti-muon: $$\mu^+ = e^+ \nu_e \bar{\nu_{\mu}}$$ all lepton numbers are conserved, but let’s now imagine the anti-muon neutrino oscillate to an anti-tau neutriono, then we finally have: $$\mu^+ = e^+ \nu_e \bar{\nu_{\tau}}$$ in which lepton number isn’t conserved, what is the theoretical explanation for this? Or do people just say that oscillations violate this conservation law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a violation of two of the three separate lepton number conservation laws. You've encountered an example of an [approximate conservation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law#Approximate_laws). The cause of these vary.

Terms in the Lagrangian either do or don't provide an opportunity for such transitions. The full Lagrangian $L_\text{total}$ can be thought of as a slight expansion around a first-order approximation $L_0$ which, were it exact, would prevent neutrino oscillation. Let's write $L_\text{total}=L_0+g\lambda$, with $\lambda$ a term that can create such interactions, so for small $g\ne0$ violations are possible but rare. (This is something of a simplification, as "rare" events tend to be more common at a suitable energy scale. Approximate conservation laws are often "valid" in a domain avoiding such a scale.)

It's even possible, though this is still under study, that some interactions may not even conserve the sum $L$ of all three lepton numbers (although your example does). It's possible the exact law [only conserves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%E2%88%92_L) $B-L$ ($B$ the baryon number) instead of $B,\,L$ separately.